# Can't upload big files in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have problem with uploading big files in wordpress. I can upload only files up to 40mb. 
Here is how looks my htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>

php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value post_max_size 300M
php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
```

My php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize= 300M
post_max_size= 300M
max_execution_time=3200 memory_limit = 300M
date.timezone=Europe/Sofia
memory=250M
expose_php=on
display_errors=on
allow_url_fopen=on
output_buffering=off
max_input_time=3600
session.gs_maxlifetime=3600
max_input_vars=1000
memory_limit=256M
extension=mysqli.so
extension=openssl.so
```

I have setted memory limit in wp-config file:
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '300M');

It's not a server host problem. They assured me that the problem is not in them.
And my question is.. What am I doing wrong? Why i cant upload files bigger than 40 MB.

Comment: Do you get any meaningful error message?

Comment: I get http error. And in post request i get :

(failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Does your host use suhosin? Also what does your error log say after you try to upload?

Comment: No, my host doesn't use suhosin. I have no registered errors in my log file.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: That is response form server when i try to upload big files:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>413 Request Entity Too Large</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Request Entity Too Large</H1>
The requested resource<BR>/www-bin/php54/wp-admin/async-upload.php<BR>
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</BODY></HTML>`

Answer (score 1):

There are a **number** of ways this could be a problem. Here is some info that could help you.

First you need to make sure you are editing the correct `php.ini` file. Depending on the setup, there are often multiple php.ini files placed on the system by control panels for specific vhosts and sometimes in the document root which will override the system version. If it's also not working via .htaccess. Something else is probably overriding it.

You can verify if the settings are taking affect by using

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are the two parameters that need to be updated via `php.ini`.

If you are using `PHP-FPM` there are also conf files that it can be put in as well which it will read from that. And all changes for PHP requires a restart of php-fpm also.

Some systems use `suhosin` so it will have a parameter that will need to be updated.

```
suhosin.post.max_value_length
```

Apache also has a `Directive` called `LimitRequestBody`. This is more rare to cause the problem but some hosts and RHEL systems set this low. If it's too low you will not be able to upload large files and need to adust this setting in `php.conf` file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

e.g. `LimitRequestBody 102400` it is messured in bytes

Also if you are using fast cgi `mod_fcgid` It too has an upload limitation aside from the php.ini parameters, which would look something like this.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 26214400
  FcgidConnectTimeout 60
</IfModule>
```

In this example it is set to 25MB and 60 Timeout.

FYI: I've seen everyone of these examples cause an upload issue at some point in time.

Even though you typically don't need to, restarting apache will not hurt as well to make sure things are effective.

Comment: That is response form server when i try to upload big files: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <HTML><HEAD> <TITLE>413 Request Entity Too Large</TITLE> </HEAD><BODY> <H1>Request Entity Too Large</H1> The requested resource<BR>/www-bin/php54/wp-admin/async-upload.php<BR> does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit. </BODY></HTML> `

Comment: Oh I thought you said it was now working for you. Hmm, did you also changed it in wordpress settings? This is definetly a server configuration issue though. Why not open a ticket to your host with that error message? That's what they are there for because they can go in your system and take a look. I can not do that. You can also make sure it's not this either http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

Comment: Sorry i had mean not working for me. I already talk with them and they tell me that everything is fine and there is no reason i can not upload big files.

Comment: Well obviously there is because you didn't imagine that error message. They sound like a lazy and pretty bad hosting company. I wouldn't use companies with bad support. That error shouldn't be difficult to track down with someone who has access to the system. Is this a word press plugin?

Comment: No. I get this response from server with Mozilla Firefox. It is not wordpress plugin.